# Clear part of div

Tags: javascript

This pop-up-category has height 0. When button is pressed, i am adding height 100%. Inside have pop-up-wrap-category div where my data is stored.
Also have div for user controls ( Close pop-up).

```
<div class="pop-up-category">
  <div class="pop-up-wrap-category">
    <p>clear just this content</p>
//this this should be still visible(populated)
    <div class="user-controls">
      <span class="close-popup btn btn-danger">Close</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js :

```
 $(document).on("click", ".close-popup", function () {
       // console.log("sdasd");
        $('.pop-up-wrap-category').empty();
    });
```

How to clear content from pop-up-wrap-category but users controls still stay visible ?

Answer (score 1):

Find the p and clear p

```
$(document).on("click", ".close-popup", function () {
     // console.log("sdasd");
     $('.pop-up-wrap-category > p').empty();  //use .remove() if you want to get the p tag deleted from DOM
});
```

Comment: @ joyBlanks What about if i have <div class="holder"></div> instead p ?

Comment: `$('.pop-up-wrap-category > p, .pop-up-wrap-category > div.holder')` if jquery finds a `p` or a `div.holder` it will empty that